# I'm trying to create custom login page with userName and Password Stored in database.but i cannot resolve this error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm a beginner for spring security, the code looks fine and I think something is missing.

while hoisting the app it will show the following error, but I have nowhere created the bean for appconfig

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-14 12:31:34.584  INFO 5148 --- [           main] com.access6.SecureDemoAppApplication     : Starting SecureDemoAppApplication on DESKTOP-G23R8VK with PID 5148 (D:\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.5.1.RELEASE\SecureDemoApp\target\classes started by Admin in D:\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.5.1.RELEASE\SecureDemoApp)
2020-03-14 12:31:34.588  INFO 5148 --- [           main] com.access6.SecureDemoAppApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-14 12:31:35.199  INFO 5148 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-14 12:31:35.255  INFO 5148 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 49ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-14 12:31:35.717  INFO 5148 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-03-14 12:31:35.724  INFO 5148 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-14 12:31:35.724  INFO 5148 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-03-14 12:31:35.918  INFO 5148 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-03-14 12:31:35.922  INFO 5148 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-14 12:31:35.922  INFO 5148 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1291 ms
2020-03-14 12:31:36.075  INFO 5148 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-14 12:31:36.133  INFO 5148 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-03-14 12:31:36.258  INFO 5148 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-14 12:31:36.451  INFO 5148 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-14 12:31:36.838  INFO 5148 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-14 12:31:36.854  INFO 5148 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-03-14 12:31:37.401  INFO 5148 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-03-14 12:31:37.408  INFO 5148 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-14 12:31:37.467  WARN 5148 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-03-14 12:31:37.710  WARN 5148 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'UserDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'reop'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.access6.User com.access6.UserRepo.findByUserName(java.lang.String)! No property userName found for type User!
2020-03-14 12:31:37.710  INFO 5148 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-14 12:31:37.713  INFO 5148 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-03-14 12:31:37.718  INFO 5148 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-03-14 12:31:37.720  INFO 5148 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-03-14 12:31:37.734  INFO 5148 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-14 12:31:37.743 ERROR 5148 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'UserDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'reop'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.access6.User com.access6.UserRepo.findByUserName(java.lang.String)! No property userName found for type User!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Here is my code:

Configuration class

```
package com.access6;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsService UserDetailsService;
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authpro() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider DAuthpro= new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        DAuthpro.setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService);
        DAuthpro.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        return DAuthpro;
    }
    @Bean
    public User u () {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

controller class

```
 package com.access6;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController
public class SecureContrlr {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView weclome() {
        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }

}
```

Model

```
package com.access6;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Repository

```
package com.access6;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
@EnableJpaRepositories
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User  findByUserName(String UserName);
}
```

Service class-something is wrong in this class but I cannot identify the problem here

```
package com.access6;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo reop;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user=reop.findByUserName(username);
        if(user==null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("404 user");

        }
        return new  UserDetailsImpli(user);
    }

}
```

implementation class

```
package com.access6;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
@Component
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UserDetailsImpli implements UserDetails {
    User user;

    public UserDetailsImpli(User user) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return user.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the method in your repository to:

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByName(String UserName);
}
```

You don't need to write the entity name in the method signature. After `findBy` the name of the field should follow, which is `name` (camelCase).

Comment: WOW just a small change helped me resolve the error thanks, big help.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom repository method is wrong. Change to:

```
User  findByName(String name);
```

Just as the exception tells you

```
No property userName found for type User!
```

The findBy* only works if name it exactly like in your model.

**Update**

First you can Google what a `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` means. Now you can read the message. This can be a bit tricky, because as in this case there can be nested exections, with difficult to read messages in one line.

Let's break it down.

This is the beginning, telling you there was a problem when creating your UserDetailsServive bean:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'UserDetailsService';
```

But the problem wasn't the service but your Repository bean:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'reop';
```

Inside the Repository bean the creation of a method failed for some reason:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo': Invocation of init method failed;
```

And there it is: spring tries to create a method findByUserName, but the User model doesn't have a property named userName:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.access6.User com.access6.UserRepo.findByUserName(java.lang.String)! No property userName found for type User!
```

Reading an exception like this you can always scroll to the far right and read the last sentence. Now you should know what to do.

Comment: thanks for your time this helped me, also can you tell me how did you read the error

Comment: I updated my answer, because comment is to short :) please accept the answer if it helped by clicking on the grey trip. Thanks!

Comment: you blow my mind!!, fantastic explanation. thanks for spending your time on this.

Comment: can you please go through this link **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701761/cannot-resolve-the-issue-with-sql-exception-while-adding-user-and-role-with-spri**

Comment: Sorry could answer earlier... Hope it helps!