# cannot resolve the issue with sql exception while adding user and role with spring security

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-security, spring-boot-maven-plugin

AppConfiguration class

```
package com.access6;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import com.access6.model.Customers;
import com.access6.model.Role;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder Encode() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
    @Bean
    public Customers c() {
        return new Customers();
    }
    @Bean
    public Role r() {
        return new Role();
    }

}
```

AppController Class

```
package com.access6.contrlr;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.access6.model.Customers;
import com.access6.model.Role;
import com.access6.repo.CustRepo;

@RestController

public class AdminContrlr {
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder PasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private CustRepo crepo;
    @Autowired
    private Customers c;

    @Autowired
    private Role r;

    @RequestMapping("/secure")
    ModelAndView enter() {
        System.out.println("started...");
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }

@PostMapping("/home")
ModelAndView home(@RequestParam("cid") int cid, @RequestParam("cname") String cname, @RequestParam("cpassword") String cpassword, @RequestParam("cemail") String cemail,@RequestParam("role_id") int role_id,@RequestParam("role") String role, ModelMap mm) {
    c.setCid(cid);
    c.setCname(cname);
    c.setCpassword(cpassword);
    c.setCemail(cemail);
    r.setRole_id(role_id);
    r.setRole(role);
    System.out.println("setters");
    mm.put("cid", cid);
    mm.put("cname",cname );
    mm.put("cemail",cemail );
    mm.put("cpassword", cpassword);
    mm.put("role_id", role_id);
    mm.put("role",role);
    System.out.println("modelmap");
    String pwd=c.getCpassword();
    String encryptpwd=PasswordEncoder.encode(pwd);
    c.setCpassword(encryptpwd);
    crepo.save(c);
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}   
}
```

Model Classes
Customers: in this class I'm not sure about cascade and join table annotations.using these entity annotation I'm able to create table but cannot insert values into table.

```
package com.access6.model;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Customers {

    @Id
private int cid;
private String cname;
private String cpassword;
private String cemail;
@OneToMany (cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="cust_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="cid;"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id;"))
private Set<Role> role;
    //getters and Setters
}
```

Role

```
package com.access6.model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int role_id;
    private String role;

 //setters and Getters
}
```

Repositories
CustRepo

```
package com.access6.repo;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;    
import com.access6.model.Customers;    
public interface CustRepo extends JpaRepository<Customers, Integer> {    
}
```

RoleRepo

```
package com.access6.repo;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.access6.model.Role;
public interface RoleRepo extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer> {
}
```

Login page: here im confused as to what components should i take from user.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>register page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>new user?</h1>
<form method="post" action="home">
<br>
id<input type="text" name=cid><br>
name<input type="text" name=cname><br>
Password<input type="text" name=cpassword><br>
email<input type="text" name=cemail><br>
role id<input type="text" name=role_id><br>
role<input type="text" name=role><br>
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the error I'm getting SQL Exception as,

```
2020-03-16 12:23:30.090  INFO 1484 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-16 12:23:30.090  INFO 1484 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-03-16 12:23:30.276  INFO 1484 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-03-16 12:23:30.279  INFO 1484 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-16 12:23:30.280  INFO 1484 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1629 ms
2020-03-16 12:23:30.438  INFO 1484 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-16 12:23:30.507  INFO 1484 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-03-16 12:23:30.673  INFO 1484 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-16 12:23:30.752  INFO 1484 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-16 12:23:31.126  INFO 1484 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-16 12:23:31.141  INFO 1484 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
Hibernate: create table cust_role (cid; integer not null, role_id; integer not null, primary key (cid;, role_id;)) engine=InnoDB
2020-03-16 12:23:31.815  WARN 1484 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table cust_role (cid; integer not null, role_id; integer not null, primary key (cid;, role_id;)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table cust_role (cid; integer not null, role_id; integer not null, primary key (cid;, role_id;)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the table `cust_role` spring is trying to create because of the `@JoinTable` in your costumer model.

```
@JoinTable(
    name="cust_role", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="cid"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
```

You have a `;` in the name of you `@JoinColumn`s.

Actually the information is not necessary. This should work as well:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int role_id;
    private String role;

    //setters and Getters
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Customers {

    @Id
    private int cid;
    private String cname;
    private String cpassword;
    private String cemail;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable
    private Set<Role> role;

    //getters and Setters
}
```

Or even simpler without the `@JoinTable` annotation. Just add a Customers field on your Role and annotate it with `@ManyToOne` :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int role_id;
    private String role;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customers customer;

    //setters and Getters
}
```

And add the `mappedBy` value in your `@OneToMany` annotation. It has to have the same name as your field in the partner class, here `customer`

```
@Entity
public class Customers {

    @Id
    private int cid;
    private String cname;
    private String cpassword;
    private String cemail;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private Set<Role> role;

    //getters and Setters
}
```

I recommand reading the posts by Vlad on mapping with Hibernate: 
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ 
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: thanks for the advice this cleared my errors, i can now insert the details for customers table but I'm unable to insert details for role table